# How to change initState in rootReducer in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, redux-reducers

I am new in Redux and I am wondering if it's possible to change one state depending on another state inside initState?

```
const initState = {
    expenses:[
        { key: '1', sum: '100'},
        { key: '2', sum: '200'},
        { key: '3', sum: '300'}
    ],
    total: 0 // I want here total sum from state above (100+200+300)
}

// let totalSum = initState.expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
// console.log(totalSum)
```

=> here I see the total, but if I put it inside initState I got nothing

Other problem for me it's change state total in rootReducer.
I don't understand why my variable let totalSum does not work in both cases? If I commit one of them it works for one case, if both are uncommitted then I get error totalSum has already been declared.

```
const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'DELETE_COST':
            let newExpenses = state.expenses.filter(cost => {
                return action.key !== cost.key
            })

            // let totalSum = state.expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
            return {
                ...state,
                total: totalSum,
                expenses: newExpenses
            }
        case 'ADD_COST':
            let totalSum = state.expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
            return {
                ...state,
                total: totalSum,
                expenses: [action.cost, ...state.expenses]
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Any suggestions?
I want to repeat I'm new in this:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem, I suggest you to initialize your state in 2 steps:

```js
const expenses = [
    { key: '1', sum: '100'},
    { key: '2', sum: '200'},
    { key: '3', sum: '300'}
];
const total = expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
const initState = {expenses, total}
```

If you don't want intermediate variables to be visible in the module, you can do it in a function:

```js
const initState = (() => {
    const expenses = [
        { key: '1', sum: '100'},
        { key: '2', sum: '200'},
        { key: '3', sum: '300'}
    ];
    const total = expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
    return {expenses, total}
})()
```

For your second problem, if I understand it well, it is a scope problem. A scope in *JavaScript* is everything between curly braces `{}`. In your `switch`/`case`, you do not use curly braces (but it is unusual to use some), so if you define the same variable in multiple `case`s statement, they actually are in the same scope. You could either use a different variable name or add curly braces in your `case`s statements:

```js
const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'DELETE_COST': {
            let newExpenses = state.expenses.filter(cost => {
                return action.key !== cost.key
            })

            let totalSum = state.expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
            return {
                ...state,
                total: totalSum,
                expenses: newExpenses
            }
        }
        case 'ADD_COST': {
            let totalSum = state.expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
            return {
                ...state,
                total: totalSum,
                expenses: [action.cost, ...state.expenses]
            }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. The second option works well, but first doesn't (prev + const initState).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, bad copy/paste. I edited my answer to correct it.